# Exception inside a Jenskinsfile pipeline stage

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm encountering a weird error inside a Jenkinsfile pipeline stage :

```
an exception which occurred:
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv@195b2bb
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CallEnv.caller
    in object com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallEnv@5866b739
    in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.e
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@c914b56
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread@aa4a561
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.threads
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@8e1e22a
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@8e1e22a
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSetList
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:568)
```

The stage is like this :

```
stage("Get issues desc") {
        steps {
          script {
            def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
            echo("changeSets = " + changeLogSets)
            def issueArray = []
            for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
              def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
              for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
                def commitMsg = entries[j].msg
                def issueNumbers = (commitMsg =~ /#(\d+)/)
                def issueNumber = issueNumbers[0][1]
                issueArray << issueNumber
              }
            }

            def issueDesc = sh(script: 'curl --globoff --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: xxxxxx" https://my-server/rest/endpoint',
                returnStdout: true)
            def issueDescJson = readJSON text: issueDesc
          }
        }
      }
```

When I move the 3 last lines (def issueDesc.... def issueDescJson) to the beginning of the same stage, I have no error

Could someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: If you are able to serialize by reorganizing the code in a manner that does not impact functionality, then I would say that your workaround is fine.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the curl command must appear after the block because my goal is to use the issueArray variable as curl parameter

Comment: Have you tried re-assigning variable values to `null` after they would no longer be useful?

Comment: Thank you for this tip, after re-assigning variables values to ```null```, it works better. Now, the question is : **why** ?